# How to move directories using jdk7

Tags: java, nio, java-7, java.nio.file

Using **jdk7**, I am trying to use the `java.nio.file.Files` class to [move](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) an empty directory, let's say `Bar`, into another empty directory, let's say `Foo`

```
Path source = Paths.get("Bar");
Path target = Paths.get("Foo");
try {
    Files.move(
        source,
        target,  
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After executing that code snippet, I expected that the `Bar` directory would be in the `Foo` directory (`...\Foo\Bar`). Instead it is not. And here's the kicker, it's been deleted as well. Also, **no exceptions were thrown**.

Am I doing this wrong?

**NOTE**

I'm looking for a **jdk7-specific** solution.I am also looking into the problem, but I figured I'd see if there was anyone else playing around with jdk7.

**EDIT**

In addition to the accepted answer, here's [another solution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve%28java.nio.file.Path%29)

```
Path source = Paths.get("Bar");
Path target = Paths.get("Foo");
try {
    Files.move(
    source,
    target.resolve(source.getFileName()),  
    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't realize jdk7 java.nio.file.Files is a necessity, so here is the edited solution.  Please see if it works coz I have never used the new Files class before.

```
Path source = Paths.get("Bar");
Path target = Paths.get("Foo", "Bar");
try {
    Files.move(
        source,
        target,  
        StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @shinkou, yes...that's why I prefaced with "Using jdk7,...". maybe I'll include a disclaimer lol

Comment: No problem.  I'm glad to know it helped.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the javadoc for the Files.move method you will find an example where it moves a file into a directory, keeping the same file name. This seems to be what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

## **Here is the solution.**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html
suppose we want to move a file to new directory, keeping the same file name, and replacing any existing file of that name in the directory:

```
Path source = ...
Path newdir = ...
Files.move(source, newdir.resolve(source.getFileName()), REPLACE_EXISTING);
//Files.move(source, newdir.resolve(source.getFileName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: This adds nothing to the solution proposed at the end of the original question.

Comment: madth3, my answer lead to the documentation where is explained how to move files and directories, with an example. And that is not explained before, so, your negative feedback it´s not apropiate, indistinctly how many points You have.