# Check if file move succeeded by Files from java nio

Tags: java, nio

I need to move files from one location to another on the unix box and I am using the below code to perform the move:

```
Path sourcePath = Paths.get(infaFileOut);
Path destinationPath = Paths.get(fileOut);
Files.move(sourcePath, destinationPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Once the file is in the destination, I need to do some additional processing. I am making the code sleep for 10 sec so that before the processing starts, the move should have already been completed. Is there any better way to make sure the move succeeded before the rest of the code runs?

Comment: I don't understand. After `Files.move` either the file was correctly moved or an exception was thrown.

Comment: There are several ways of implementing this. You could run a check after the move operation to check that the new files exist in the new location. And only return back to the main process a successful value, if all the files have been moved appropriately. That way, you don't start the 2nd part of processing until it has been finished AND verified as successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a search before posting:

Sources:

- [How to move directories using jdk7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210433/how-to-move-directories-using-jdk7)
- [Moving files from one directory to another with Java NIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356585/moving-files-from-one-directory-to-another-with-java-nio)

  ```
  Path sourcePath = Paths.get(infaFileOut);
  Path destinationPath = Paths.get(fileOut);
  try{
  Files.move(sourcePath, destinationPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
  } catch (IOException e) {
      //this is where the error will be thrown if the file did not move properly 
      //(null pointer etc...), you can place code here to run if there is an error
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

  If your extra paranoid try printing out everything:

  ```
     Path sourceDir = Paths.get("c:\\source");
      Path destinationDir = Paths.get("c:\\dest");

      try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(sourceDir)) {
          for (Path path : directoryStream) {
              System.out.println("copying " + path.toString());
              Path d2 = destinationDir.resolve(path.getFileName());
              System.out.println("destination File=" + d2);
              Files.move(path, d2, REPLACE_EXISTING);
          }
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }
  ```